# Kibana+elasticsearch breaking messages into words

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I want to analyse messages in my kibana panel:
[image]

I don't want it to be tokenized.

I am shipping logs via filebeat and adding filters in logstash.

With the help of [Logstash + Kibana terms panel without breaking words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937570/logstash-kibana-terms-panel-without-breaking-words), the curl command I am using to update is:

```
curl -XPUT https://localhost:9200/_template/filebeat -d '
{
    "template": "filebeat-*",
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "properties": {
               "message": {
                  "type": "multi_field",
                  "fields": {
                     "message": {
                         "type": "string",
                         "index": "analyzed"
                     },
                     "untouched": {
                         "type": "string",
                         "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

But the response is:

```
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

What am I doing wrong? What I need to do to achieve the desired result.

Edit : The issue with the above curl command was using `https` instead of `http`. But, still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom analyzer and set its tokenizer to 'keyword' as below.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
             "analyzer":{
               "my_analyzer":{

                   "tokenizer":   {"keyword"},
                   "filter":      {" Standard Token Filter", "Lower Case Token Filter", "Stop Token Filter"},

                }
             }
        }
    }
    "mappings": ..........
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: so, you dont want it to be tokenized but want it filtered right. So make this custom analyzer before mappings. and add change messages field to                      "message": {
                         "type": "string",
                         "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                     }, have a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/configuring-analyzers.html